# How can I extract an item ID from an HTML file using shell tools?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a text file with catalog names (one per line) and I need to open and cycle through that list. Taking one name at a time, downloading the corresponding HTML page and extracting the "item_id" that is on the page.

The item ID is displayed like this in the HTML: `?item_id=55963573">`.

This is what I have so far below.

```
#!/bin/sh

for productID in (catIDs.txt) #I know this part is not correct
do
    wget -q -U Mozilla "http://www.example.com/$productID/" -O - \
     | tr '"' '\n' | grep "^item_id" | cut -d ' ' -f 4 >> itemIDs.txt
    sleep 15
done
```

Comment: `grep "^item_id"` will look for lines in the HTML that being with item_id. It sounds like you need something like a sed to do what you want. Something like - `sed -e 's#\?item_id=\([:digit:]*\)#\1#g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read productID; do
    wget -q -U Mozilla "http://www.example.com/$productID/" -O - |
    sed -n -r 's/.*\?item_id=([0-9]+)"\>.*/\1/p'
done <catIDs.txt >itemIDs.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is small, use:

```
for productID in `cat catIDs.txt`
```

Comment: about 150,000 is that considered small for the code you listed above?

Comment: not really... but with that many downloads you need a better solution, what if there is a crash in the middle of process (with that sleep it will take about a month to download)

Answer (score 1):

```
cat catIDs.txt | while read productID;
do
  wget -q -U Mozilla "http://www.domain.com/$productID/" -O - \
  | tr '"' '\n' | grep "^item_id" | cut -d ' ' -f 4 >> itemIDs.txt
  sleep 15
done
```

or

```
while read productID;
do
  wget -q -U Mozilla "http://www.domain.com/$productID/" -O - \
  | tr '"' '\n' | grep "^item_id" | cut -d ' ' -f 4 >> itemIDs.txt
  sleep 15
done < catIDs.txt
```